# Removing [Author Year] Tags from Reference List using ACM Journal Style

Tags: bibtex, acm

How can I remove the tags before each bibliographic entry in the list (and also remove the paragraph indentation if possible? Also, is the version without the [Author Year] a valid ACM bibliography style at all?

(See image attached please)

My code for the bibliography is this:

```
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format-Journals}
\bibliography{library}
```

Thanks.[image]

Comment: It's always best to provide the community with a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). It just makes it easier to start working with towards a solution. Your MWE should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your copy of the style file `ACM-Reference-Format-Journals.bst` is more or less the same as the one I was able to obtain from [this GitHub site](https://github.com/vrdabomb5717/CSS_Final_Project), you can get rid of the bracketd citation labels by loading the `natbib` package (in the preamble):

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

To get rid of the handing indentation, use the instruction

```
\setlength\bibhang{0pt}
```

You don't mention the document class you use or if you load any packages that perform citation management chores, so this is as far as I can go in giving advice.

Comment: Thanks, this contributed to fixing my problem. I will post  my final document preamble to help others!

Answer (score 0):

My final document preamble (thanks to Mico for pointing me in the right direction)

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}         %ACM template for conference proceedings

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}                %for special characters

\usepackage{listings}                       %for code sections
\usepackage[square,authoryear]{natbib}      %for bibliography parametrization (inline citations with square brackets and author-year configuration)
\setcitestyle{square,aysep={},yysep={;}}    %remove the comma between author and year from the default inline citation style (from section 2.9 of natbib documentation http://mirrors.fe.up.pt/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf)
\let\cite\citep                             % make \cite command behave like \citep

\usepackage{url}                            %\url command
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}     %hide color boxes around links
```

The bibliography style:

```
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format-Journals}
\bibliography{library}  % library.bib is the name of the Bibliography in this case
```